# Are all languages related?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, linguistics, language

This question was prompted by this [newspaper article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2013/may/06/european-asian-language-tongue-superfamily) saying:

> Languages spoken by billions of people across Europe and Asia are descended from an ancient tongue uttered in southern Europe at the end of the last ice age, according to research...by scientists in Britain, [and] points to a common origin for vocabularies as varied as English and Urdu, Japanese and Itelmen, a language spoken along the north-eastern edge of Russia.

Linguistics conventionally divide human languages into families. For example the Indo-European family which contains Latin, Sanskrit and Greek amongst others.

However it seems to me that all languages must be related in the same way that all life on Earth is related even though there are marked similarities between certain species.

I cannot see how, even taking into account Chomskys idea of a universal grammar intrinsic to the human mind, how a language can spontaneously develop in total absence of another human being simply because a human babies and infants are utterly helpless and dependent. (Is there any evidence of this ever occurring)?

That is there is always *spoken* linguistic continuity.

Is this correct? Or am I missing something? Or is it a trite truth?

The point of the question, is that if Chomskys Universal Grammar hypothesis is correct, and I suspect it is; then language contrary to the above hypothesis orginated where Man originated - in the African continent and marched out of it when he did too.

Comment: Related, but not about _single_ isolated humans: http://www.forbes.com/2005/10/19/chomsky-noam-language-invention-comm05-cx_de_1024chomskyinvent.html

Comment: @Gugg: Interesting case studies. I've come across it before in some other context. I think that it is evidence for Chomskys universal grammar. I'll change my question to *spoken* linguistic continuity.

Comment: Related, still not about _single_ isolated humans, but with mute parents and a TV, single negative case: http://www.earlychildhoodnews.com/earlychildhood/article_view.aspx?ArticleID=119

Comment: @Gugg: I don't think that counts. Presumably the mute parents can *listen* and so TV is part of their lingustic community.

Comment: No, they are deaf too. And it is a _negative_ case: The child _doesn't_ learn to speak.

Comment: I'd recommend researching the stages infant language acquisition, specifically, the stage at about 10 months when babies begin declarative pointing. This is kind of a Rosetta Stone moment for the baby, as the language of pointing can then rapidly facilitate the decoding the parent language by asking the names of things. The fact that all humans have been doing this since before we even had verbal language is probably one of the biggest clues to a universal grammar if one actually exists.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'm having some language difficulties with "too" and "as well" and "also". I meant that the parents are deaf and mute. The child is "normal" and watches the TV. Hopefully, with the sound on. :)

Comment: @Gugg: I've read that part of the article. The story isn't referenced in the bibliography at the end. Frankly, I'm a little incredulous. Did these parents have no friends, no relatives to show off the baby to? Was there no nurse to check on the baby development. Presumably some professionals were involved otherwise the scientific team wouldn't have been notified. How long did the observation go on for? If it was for a substantial length of time - then it would seem to go against basic medical ethics.

Comment: @DavidH: I suspect that language acquisition ability remains and atrophies in the adult. It surprising how far one can get in a foreign country without knowing the language by gestures, facial expression and pointing. How does pointing allow the child to acquire verbs?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Further (negative) cases: [Justin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_D._Perry), [Victor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_of_Aveyron), [Frederick II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_deprivation_experiments)

Comment: Take a look at this question, about [Monogenesis vs. Polygenesis](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/682/22)

Comment: @Macedo: Thanks, very useful. It doesn't directly answer my question but indirectly implies - yes, they are. It also tangentially answers another one which I didn't think appropriate for this site.

Comment: Just in passing -- universal grammar doesn't necessarily imply all extant languages have a common ancestor; I feel like I might be missing something :)

Comment: This might be interesting to consider in this context: http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/linguists-identify-15000-year-old-ultraconserved-words/2013/05/06/a02e3a14-b427-11e2-9a98-4be1688d7d84_story.html